# how to unit test angular form validation with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have created a basic page, which validates input.

How to unit test form validation??

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
// create angular app
 var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

var vm = this;
// function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
vm.submitForm = function() {

  // check to make sure the form is completely valid
  if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
    alert('our form is amazing');
  }

};
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="vm.submitForm()" novalidate>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
          <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
          <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
          <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
          <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do following way.
This is only for example form validation. but before you doing this we need to configure [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor)

```
var scope, htmlForm;

beforeEach(function() {
  module('module');

});

beforeEach(inject($rootScope, $controller, $templateCache, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()

    templateHtml = $templateCache.get('sample/sample.html')
    formElement = angular.element("<div>" + templateHtml + "</div>")
    $compile(formElement)(scope)
    htmlForm= scope.htmlForm

    scope.$apply()
}

it('should not allow an invalid `width`', function() {
  expect(htmlForm.$valid).toBeTruthy();
  htmlForm.number.$setViewValue('LORA');
  expect(htmlForm.number.$valid).toBeFalsy()
});
```